# Why do you need to add variables when multiplying through by a constant?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, schroedinger-equation

I was reading the following paper: http://vixra.org/abs/1206.0055 when I came across equation 9 on page two. The author claims that when multiplying equation 8 through by the constant A, you need to add to more variables. Then, again when they divide by A, they add even two more, and end up with four extra variables. They claim that the reason this must be done is because it is describing a physical system, but I do not understand where this reasoning comes from. I admit that I did not read any of the references in detail, but this specific idea is not cited anyway. Can anyone help me understand what is going on here?

Comment: This article looks like a bunch of nonsense

Comment: Thank god. I thought I was either going crazy or had been drugged. I had a hang up in every other paragraph and was very concerned. Should I just delete this post?

Comment: Nonsense on viXra? I’m shocked, shocked!

Comment: I'd wait a bit. I'd never believe just one person, even if it is myself haha

Comment: vixra accepts "alternative science" papers but I thought that there was some review , even though not peer review. even the abstract " Hence, we argue that the Schrödinger equation is unsuitable to be applied to any physical systems" is off reality, as the S equation is a good approximation for the quantum framework without special relativity. On the extra variables, one can add as many as one wants to complicate equations as long as the algebra is correct. video games.

Comment: Yeah, when I first read G. Smith's comment I thought I'd investigate the site (not sure why this didn't occur to me before). I'm a chemist by trade and there were a bunch of nonsense chemistry papers. I also looked in the thermo/StatMech section and found nonsense too. Sorry folks! I hadn't heard of this site before.

Before when I was looking at their equation 9, I noticed that it did all simplify down so it was fine. But they had been claiming that you "had to" do this, which is what threw me off.

Comment: @Ben would you mind editing your post to contain the equations you're asking about - enough that, if the original paper became inaccessible, people could still make sense of the question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question. The paper is nonsense. Thank you to those who responded. I'm going to leave the post up in case anyone else in the future naively gets fooled into thinking the material is serious.